# jq delete nested entries matching one of multiple strings

Tags: jq

I'm trying to use jq to edit a composer.json file between development and production.

I've got to the point where I can **select** the items that I want to remove, but I can't figure out how to turn that into a **delete** statement.

Also - the only way I could get the select working is to use to_entries, which then breaks the structure of the require selection.

Any help would be appreciated!

composer.json (trimmed for a shorter post):

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.0",
        "kreait/laravel-firebase": "^4.1",
        "laravel/cashier-paddle": "^1.5",
        "laravel/framework": "^8.75",
        "laravel/sanctum": "^2.11",
        "laravel/socialite": "^5.5",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "livewire/livewire": "^2.5",
        "lorisleiva/laravel-actions": "^2.4",
        "owenvoke/blade-fontawesome": "*",
        "protonemedia/laravel-verify-new-email": "^1.5",
        "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^7.0",
        "rapidstatic/rapidstatic": "dev-master",
        "rapidstatic/scraper": "dev-master",
        "razorui/blade-application-ui": "^0.3.0"
    }
}
```

jq:

```
jq '.require | to_entries | map(select(.key | contains("rapidstatic")))' composer.json
```

output:

```
[
  {
    "key": "rapidstatic/rapidstatic",
    "value": "dev-master"
  },
  {
    "key": "rapidstatic/scraper",
    "value": "dev-master"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `del` and provide the key names as follows:

```
jq '.require |= del(.[keys[] | select(contains("rapidstatic"))])' composer.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/rCSVjS-TNM4)

Or you could generate an array of path expressions and use `delpaths` on them:

```
jq '.require |= delpaths([keys[] | select(contains("rapidstatic")) | [.]])' composer.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/O0wWtMwchiy)

Output:

```json
{
  "name": "laravel/laravel",
  "type": "project",
  "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
  "keywords": [
    "framework",
    "laravel"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "require": {
    "php": "^8.0",
    "kreait/laravel-firebase": "^4.1",
    "laravel/cashier-paddle": "^1.5",
    "laravel/framework": "^8.75",
    "laravel/sanctum": "^2.11",
    "laravel/socialite": "^5.5",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
    "livewire/livewire": "^2.5",
    "lorisleiva/laravel-actions": "^2.4",
    "owenvoke/blade-fontawesome": "*",
    "protonemedia/laravel-verify-new-email": "^1.5",
    "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^7.0",
    "razorui/blade-application-ui": "^0.3.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, you sir, are a star! Thank you so much. I've not come across delpath before. Appreciate your fast help!